# Google Sheets, coloring a line depending on another column (conditional formatting for lines)

Tags: conditional-formatting, google-sheets-charts

Imagine I have a table like the following.

[image]

Column A is the x-axis, e.g. time. Column B is some condition, e.g. 1 and 0 for yes and no or true and false. Column C has the y-values.
I'd like to create a line chart that changes color depending on Column B, as in the following Figure (made manually in GeoGebra).

[image]

However, I have absolutely no clue and cannot find anything. Perhaps I am looking for the wrong words.

Comment: I uploaded a pictture! Thanks for looking at the problem

Answer (score 1):

##### Formula in `B2`

```
=MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(FILTER(color, LEN(color)>=0))), color, values,
   LAMBDA(squ, col, val, 
     IF(col=1, 
        IF(AND(OFFSET(col,-1,0)<>1, squ<>1),
          {val,val}, {val,""}),
        IF(OFFSET(col, -1, 0)=1,
          {val,val}, {"", val}))
 ))
```

[image]

##### Named Ranges

| Name | Range | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **`color`** | `E2:E21` | Holds the color flags: `=1` or `<>1`) |
| **`values`** | `F2:F21` | Contains all the entered values |

##### Chart Customizations

| Section | Customization |
| --- | --- |
| Setup > Chart type | Line chart |
| Setup > Data Range | `A1:B21,C1:C21` |
| Setup > Combine ranges | Horizontally |
| Setup > X-axis | Time |
| Setup > Series | Value01 Value02 ✔️ Use row 1 as headers ✔️ Use column A as labels |
| Customize > Chart & axis titles > Chart title > Title text | Value vs. Time |
| Customize > Legend > Position | None |

[image]   [image]   [image]

<sub>**Note:** I repurposed this chart in [another related solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/169960) asking about alternating background colors.</sub>