# Change colors on graph

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a graph on google sheets, and want to change the background color for certain values on x axis. For example,  from a value A to a value B (on x axis) I want a background color 1, then from point B to value C I want another color,...

Thank you for your help

---

[image]

This but horizontally. With background colors

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the chart **"Background color"** offers only a single choice.
 **`Chart editor > Customize > Chart Style > Background color`**

#### You Could Simulate Background Colors

You could however simulate different background colors by strategically filling cells located behind the chart.

<sub>**Simulated Background Colors**</sub>
[image]

### Instructions

1. Create a chart with a clear background;
2. Hide (uncheck) **"Gridlines"**
   `"View" (menu) > "Show" > "Gridlines"`
3. Color the cells beside your chart ("Fill color");
4. Drag your chart on top of the colored cells;
5. Tweak column widths and row heights as necessary;

<sub>**Hide (uncheck) "Gridlines"**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**Color the cells beside your chart**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**Drag your chart on top of the colored cells**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**Note:** *I repurposed the Line Chart from [this solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/169793)*</sub>